# How to declutter admin columns

Tags: wp-admin

As the number of activated plugins increases, many of the admin columns are getting so cluttered that it's becoming hard to read the content of the names and modify them. Is there a way to fix this?

[image: Admin columns]

Comment: Please edit this question if "menu" is not the correct term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admin columns can be shown/hidden by using the *Screen Options* menu. Here, the custom column *Headline news* is being hidden using the UI:

[image: Toggle admin columns]

Alternatively, Admin Columns can be unset (and therefore hidden) programmatically:

```
add_filter( 'manage_post_posts_columns', 'wpse_hide_columns', PHP_INT_MAX, 1 );
function wpse_hide_columns( $columns ) {
    // Check for the name of the column, and unset it if it exits.
    if ( isset( $columns['headline_news'] ) ) {
        unset( $columns['headline_news'] );
    }

    return $columns;
}
```

Comment: I was using Ultimo WP which obscured the 'Screen Options' tab so I simply deactivated it, made the changes, and reactivated it. Major help :-)

Comment: Glad to help and thanks for the note about the Ultimo WP plugin!